# jquery mobile checkbox styling issue

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox

Using jquery mobile.

Try to make the disabled checkbox visible. height/width can be overridden.

```
<div class=" ui-checkbox ui-state-disabled">
 <input type="checkbox" name="foo" checked="checked" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

Why the position is !important, and it can not be overridden. As a result, it can not align well with neighboring elements in different situations.

```
.ui-checkbox input:disabled, .ui-radio input:disabled {
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
}
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: I can use style to override position, but it is not the preferred way to do. Try to understand why jquery mobile want to make it invisible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use jQM styling, put the checkbox within a LABEL (whether you have text or not). Then when the widget is enhanced, if it is disabled, the opacity is used to dim the checkbox.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /> Check me   
</label>    
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bar" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />    
</label>
```

jQM actually hides the INPUT element and styles the label to be the checkbox.

If on the other hand, you want jQM to leave the checkbox unstyled, add data-role="none":

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bar" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" data-role="none" />
```